# How to send emails using rich textbox Ui with Google AppScript and Html file?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

Please help me to understand how to make this happen in google AppScript and Html files?
Is there any predefined class available to use the
`Compose Email menu in Gmail Web app`.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? I am assuming that you would like to use rich textbox features when sending an email in AppsScript, is that correct?

Comment: yes @OriolCastander you are right. Also I want a UI which helps me to do it easily as displayed in this image

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can style your emails using the HTML programming language, and you can do it either using the UI (where the programming is handled by the **Textbox** and you don't have to do any yourself), or you can specify your HTML code that you want the email to render.

In AppsScript, only the second option is available. You can send an email with HTML in its body by using the `sendEmail()` function in the `MailApp` class (you can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))), where in the **htmlBody** you pass a string containing the desired HTML.

Here is a small example outlining some basic things that you can do in HTML.

```js
function myFunction() {

  var htmlBody = "<html><body><h1>My title</h1><b>My bold text</b> My regular text. <p style='color:Tomato;'>My color text</p><p align='center'>My centered text</p></body></html>";

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "", // RECIPIENT'S ADDRESS
    subject: "Example",
    htmlBody: htmlBody});
}
```